# Queue list of SQL commands to run at a later time without PostBack

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a fairly long modal form displaying information to the user. The user is able to add new records and delete records (from a gridview), and update information through normal form fields. While I'd like to show the changes on the form, I do not want to save the changes to the database until the `Submit` button is clicked. I thought I could Queue the SQL commands in a List and run them all once `Submit` is clicked

However, I'd like to do this without having to do a postback each time a gridview is updated as waiting for the server to respond can be quite annoying if adding/deleting a lot of items. Is this possible only using JavaScript/jQuery, only doing a postback once `submit` is clicked? The only way I could think of is to append the SQL to a hidden HTML tag and run its contents when submitting, but of course that is not very secure.

Alternatively, is there a way to do this through ASP itself and I am just completely over thinking this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Ajax` see documentation (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Is it possible, yes. If that isn't your question then you need to clarify what **exactly** you want here. Tl;dr `ajax`. This question is almost certainly far too broad

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have a couple gridviews inside the same page. When a row is added or deleted, a postback is firing to delete/add that specific row in the database. The normal form fields are not a problem

Comment: You should definitely not queue up SQL commands directly. That puts the user in control of the SQL that gets run - a security problem. You can come up with a way of specifying operations to happy, and then have your server side interpret those and generate the necessary SQL commands to make it happen.